# Query multiple tables using PhpMyedit

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I write a select query in phpmyedit (http://www.phpmyedit.org/) to query multiple tables.

I know to query a single table I just need to write `$opts ['tb'] = 'table_one';`

Is there some option to query in more tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve it. This is how I did it.

```
$opts['fdd']['name'] = array(
    'name'     => 'User Name',
    'select'   => 'T',
    'input'   => 'V', // virtual
    'options'  => 'L', // list only
    'size|F' => 50,
    'values'   => Array('table' => 'users',
                        'column' => 'id', 
                        'description' => 'name',
                        'join' => '$main_table.userID = $join_table.id'),
    'sql'      => 'name',
    'sort'     => true
);
```

Here I am joining two tables with the `userID` from the first table `$main_table`  and `id` from the second table `$join_table` .Also in the field
`sql` .I have specified the `name` of the attribute to appear in the SQL query. So I can display this under the field `User Name`by the value     `['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Does not work with phpMyEdit.class.php version, v 1.215 2011-01-09

```
$opts['fdd']['fOpenDate'] = array(
  'name'     => 'OpenDate',
  'options'  => 'VCDR',
  'select'   => 'T',
  'input'   => 'VR', // virtual
  'values'   => Array('table' => 'scan233e__233d_version',
        'column' => 'Vers233d_PK',
        'description' => 'fOpenDate',
        'join' => '$main_table.scan233d_LastVersion_ID = $join_table.Vers233d_PK'),
    'sql'      => 'fOpenDate'
```

*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PMEtable0.fOpenDate' in 'field list'*

....AS `qf21`,`PMEtable0`.`scan233d_LastVersion_ID` AS `qf22`,**`PMEtable0`.`fOpenDate` AS `qf23`**,fOpenDate AS `qf23_idx` FROM....

It displays the `PMEtable0`.`fOpenDate` field which does not exist in the primary table instead of taking the field from the secondary table